# Error with setup.py egg_info while pip-installing my own package

Tags: python, pip, setuptools, pypi, python-packaging

I am building a python package via `pip`and `setuptools`. I am testing it on `test.pypi` and I am building it following [this guide](https://betterscientificsoftware.github.io/python-for-hpc/tutorials/python-pypi-packaging/).

Prior to building the package and uploading, I made sure to update everything I need with

```
pip install --upgrade pip setuptools
```

My project directory is structured as follows:

```
mypackage
|_ /mypackage
|_ /docs
|_ /demos
|_ LICENSE
|_ README.md
|_ requirements.txt
|_ setup.py
|_ /tests
```

While building, everything runs smoothly. In my project directory, I run the following commands:

```
 python setup.py check
 python setup.py sdist
 python setup.py bdist_wheel --universal
 python setup.py egg_info
 twine upload --repository-url https://test.pypi.org/legacy/ dist/mypackage-0.0.2.tar.gz
```

It successfully builds, adding the folders `mypackage.egg-info`, `dist` and `build` to my project folder.

However, when I try to install it by doing

```
pip install -i https://test.pypi.org/simple/ mypackage
```

I get the following error:

```
Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  × python setup.py egg_info did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [8 lines of output]
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "<string>", line 2, in <module>
        File "<pip-setuptools-caller>", line 34, in <module>
        File "/private/var/folders/1l/rpytfnks7cg8cqm_7qp4r_v40000gn/T/pip-install-_mx6wquv/mypackage_5557314a6a5a415c90c3b8da2b6c8efa/setup.py", line 11, in <module>
          with open(path.join(here, "requirements.txt"), encoding="utf-8") as f:
        File "/Users/myname/opt/anaconda3/envs/pip_mypackage/lib/python3.10/codecs.py", line 906, in open
          file = builtins.open(filename, mode, buffering)
      FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/private/var/folders/1l/rpytfnks7cg8cqm_7qp4r_v40000gn/T/pip-install-_mx6wquv/mypackage_5557314a6a5a415c90c3b8da2b6c8efa/requirements.txt'
      [end of output]
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: metadata-generation-failed

× Encountered error while generating package metadata.
╰─> See above for output.

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for details.
```

It looks like it is not able to locate the `requirements.txt` file at some point during the process. The error stays even if I specify the requirements directly in `setup.py`instead of sourcing them from the external file.

I am not sure what I am missing and how I can fix the issue on my own package. Please let me know if I can provide further details.

Comment: create a file `MANIFEST.in` and add following line into it: `include requirements.txt`

Comment: Point being; requirements.txt is available in your repository but its not included in the package itself unless you include it with manifest ..

Comment: thanks for your reply! but it is still not working

Comment: it could then be issue with your setup.py .. However, any files that your setup.py reads (like requirements.txt in this) **has to be included in manifest.in** and if that doesnt work, you have other issues but without seeing your full manifest and setup.py file, there's no way to pinpoint where the issue really is.